# Is there a process beyond just guessing and doing a lot of algebra to prove this inequality in Beckenbach's Inequalities book?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality, soft-question, problem-solving

There's a question in chapter 2 page 19 that says:

3. Show that
   $$
   \left(a^2-b^2\right)^2 \geq 4 a b(a-b)^2
   $$
   for all $a, b$, and that the sign of equality holds if and only if $a=b$.

And the answer also included has no explanation:

3. Equivalent to $(a-b)^4 \geq 0$

And I completely believe it, but the book never presented any strategies for inequality solving so am I supposed to just expand everything out and then recognize that it looks like $(a-b)^4$ ? Is there a better way? Is there a different book I should be using if this one isn't explaining the tricks?

I'm just really bad at inequalities (especially with absolute values) and I want to get better at the basics so I can do well at Abbott's Analysis type problems

Comment: Something trivial that you can do to check/prove the inequality do is expanding both equations into monomials and see if you get the same result. Maybe you can add this check to your question

Comment: This does not let you "discover" the inquality of course... but once you know it you get a proof

Comment: Yeah I think if I'm understanding what you're saying (is monomial expanding it all the way?), I did do that it was just kind of busy work, like I subtracted the right side from the left side, expanded and canceled terms and then got the expanded version of (a-b)^4, but that seems like I'm missing something and also I'm worried in future problems I won't recognize the form of (a-b)^4 without having the answer key

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid expanding all of the brackets by spotting the common factor:
$$\begin{aligned}(a^2-b^2)^2-4ab(a-b)^2&=(a-b)^2(a+b)^2-4ab(a-b)^2\\
&=(a-b)^2((a+b)^2-4ab)\\
&=(a-b)^2(a-b)^2\\
&=(a-b)^4
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: This was helpful but where can I learn these tricks? The next question says something like 4. Show that
$$
\left(a^2-b^2\right)\left(a^4-b^4\right) \leq\left(a^3-b^3\right)^2
$$ with the answer "Equivalent to $a^2 b^2(a-b)^2 \geq 0$" just completely unexplained :( Where can I go to learn how to do these things

Comment: @username_entity For that one it's probably quicker to expand the brackets $$(a^3-b^3)^2-(a^2-b^2)(a^4-b^4)=-2a^3b^3+a^2b^4+a^4b^2=a^2b^2(a-b)^2$$ You will get better at realising which technique to use with experience.

Comment: Okay thanks, I think I'm going to do AOPS or some other math Olympiad book since this seems like a bottleneck for meeeee :)

Comment: @username_entity Keep persevering and soon you'll find it easy :)

Answer (score 2):

For $a=b$ there is evidently equality. You may assume that $a\neq b$.
Write the left hand side as
$$(a-b)^2(a+b)^2$$
Cancel the positive $(a-b)^2$ on both sides to get
$$(a+b)^2>4ab$$
which is obvious, because it is equivalent to
$$(a-b)^2>0$$
(remember that $a\neq b$).

This is not much of a trick, but also not much of algebra.